# Pandas parsing errors due to extra commas in columns when trying to append rows to SQL table using read_csv w/to_sql

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pandas-to-sql

I'm trying to update a table in my database with any new rows from a .csv file that contains just 2 columns with a comma as the delimiter.

However, each of these columns contains many extra commas (and double-quotes, single-quotes, spaces etc.) Both columns are data type TEXT.

Below is a sample of the kind of text in each column:

column 1 (named: filename)
**Note: The following occur throughout the text: , (commas), ", ', "" (consecutive double quotes), '' (consecutive single quotes)**

DOH_cumulative_text_filesSwimming PoolsSpas_52-60-1632726_6West Beach Cottages_13354 Gulf Boulevard_Madeira Beach_20181219_Inspection.69.pdf.txt

column 2 (named: content)
STATE OF  FLORIDA DEPARTMENTOF  HEALTH COUNTY  HEALTH  DEPARTMENT PUBLIC  POOL AND BATHING  PLACE INSPECTION  REPORT **** DowningBK 12/20/2018 4: 01: 21  PM  ****1  of 2 Facility Information Permit  Number: 52-60-1632726 Name  of Facility: 6West  Beach  Cottages Address: 13354 Gulf Boulevard City, Zip: Madeira  Beach33708

It is worth noting that the text strings in column 2 are always about 4-6k characters long, including spaces.

I've tried changing the script that creates these .csv files to use a delimiter that doesn't ever occur in the text string (i.e. "~") but doing so resulted in the same error "pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2".

Here is the code that creates the `.csv` from multiple `.txt` files:

```
with open('doh_reports'+timestamp()+'.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    csv_out = csv.writer(out_file)
    csv_out.writerow(['filename', 'content'])
    for filename in Path('.').glob('*.txt'):
        csv_out.writerow([str(filename),open(str(filename.absolute())).read().replace('\n','').strip()])
```

Here is the code I'm using to upload to the database:
(I've written so that the table in my database continuously imports any new rows from any `.csv` files in the directory.)

```
path =r'/Users/.../DOH_cumulative'

allFiles = os.listdir(path)

df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f,engine='c',na_values='',keep_default_na='False') for f in allFiles),ignore_index=True)

df.to_sql(name='doh_test',con=dbconn,if_exists='append',index=False)
```

I tried changing the read_csv code to the following and still get the same error "pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 4":

```
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f,engine='c',doublequote=True,delimiter=',',quoting=3,index_col=False) for f in allFiles),ignore_index=True)
df=df.replace({'"': '','\'':''}, regex=True)
```

I've tried both the 'c' and 'python' engines in pandas. But when I use the python engine I get a null byte error.

I've tried different na_values and different quoting values without success. What should I do with the read_csv line or to_sql line to make this work?

Comment: I got this to work by changing the read_csv code to the following: for files in source:
    if files.endswith(".csv"):
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(sourcepath,files))
        df.to_sql(name='doh_test',con=dbconn,if_exists='append',index=False)

Answer (score 0):

I just got this to work by changing the database import code to the following:

```
for files in source:
    if files.endswith(".csv"):
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(sourcepath,files))
        df.to_sql(name='doh_test',con=dbconn,if_exists='append',index=False)
```